# ¿Como solucionar el siguiente error en un boton c#?

Tags: c#

quiero hacer un total de las filas de una tabla, pero me da el siguiente error: en Cells.

```
        private void btnConsultarMarca_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        dgvListaVentas.DataSource = TrabajarVentas.TraerVentasPorMarcaSP(cmbMarca.Text);
        double total = 0;

        foreach (DataGridView row in dgvListaVentas.Rows)
        {
            total += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Colum14"].Value);
        }
        txtCantidadVentas.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
    }
```

Error   1   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' no contiene una definición de 'Cells' ni se encontró ningún método de extensión 'Cells' que acepte un primer argumento de tipo 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' (¿falta una directiva de uso o una referencia de ensamblado?)    C:\Users\lisan\OneDrive\Desktop\repaso2-lpoo1\TrabajoPracticoFinal\LPOO1_GRUPO01_tp3\Vistas\FrmListaVentas.cs   92  47  Vistas

Comment: Coloque una respuesta que ya fue punteada, me gustaría que si la respuesta te resultó satisfactoria, que la marcaras como aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

Tu error radica en que estas haciendo un `foreach` por la colección `dgvListaVentas.Rows` pero has declarado la variable `DataGridView row`que es de un tipo diferente, la variable debe declarase de la siguiente forma `DataGridViewRow row` es decir tu código quedaria como sigue

```
{
        private void btnConsultarMarca_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        dgvListaVentas.DataSource = TrabajarVentas.TraerVentasPorMarcaSP(cmbMarca.Text);
        double total = 0;
        //foreach (DataGridView row in dgvListaVentas.Rows) cambia esta linea por la siguiente.
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvListaVentas.Rows)
        {
            total += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Colum14"].Value);
        }
        txtCantidadVentas.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

el control DataGridView que yo sepa no tiene esa propiedad rows[], intenta usar la propiedad Columns[] en su defecto.

Comment: El control `DataGridView` si tiene la propiedad `rows[]`, con la propiedad `Columns[]` no es posible resolver se problema.